# clojure: compute a new key/val pair in a map based on other key/val pairs

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of maps which represents a DataFrame. I want to compute a new column (key/val pairs for all maps in the vector). Need some help to do this in the most efficient and idiomatic way.

```clj
(def dt [{:foo 10 :bar 20 :cat "A"}
         {:foo 15 :bar 10 :cat "B"}
         {:foo 12 :bar 15 :cat "C"}
         {:foo 16 :bar 22 :cat "A"}
         {:foo 13 :bar 11 :cat "B"}
         {:foo 10 :bar 19 :cat "C"}])
```

What I want to do is define :baz = :foo + :bar. I can get the computation done with a map operation as follows.

```
(map #(+ (:foo %) (:bar %)) dt)
```

I would prefer to write a function where the vector is maps is the last argument, so that I can chain operations with the thread-last macro

Something like this:

```
(->> dt
     (filter #(= (:foo %) 10))
     (compute-new-column #(...)))
```

I am beginner in both Clojure and FP, so any additional insights would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Apologies, my attempt was incorrect/misleading. What I am looking for is the output as below by Christian ```({:foo 10, :bar 20, :cat "A", :baz 30} {:foo 10, :bar 19, :cat "C", :baz 29})```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to add a new key value pair to each map in your collection based on `:foo` and `:bar`.

```
(defn compute-new-column [row]
  (assoc row :baz (+ (:foo row) (:bar row))))
```

Then you can map this function in your thread macro. This is easily done with an anonymous function too as you are doing in your filter.

```
(->> dt
     (filter #(= (:foo %) 10))
     (map compute-new-column))


({:foo 10, :bar 20, :cat "A", :baz 30} {:foo 10, :bar 19, :cat "C", :baz 29})
```

Comment: My preference is to pass to pass the column name and the function as arguments to  compute-new-column as: ```(defn compute-new-column [row colname f]
  (assoc row (keyword colname) (f row)))```

Comment: (keyword :foo) and (keyword "foo") both give :foo -- which is what I want

Comment: @anerjee If you are dealing with say JSON and you have mixed worlds in regard to string keys or keywords, disable automatic "keywordization" for JSON.  `keyword` accepts any nonsense that could lead to confusion later (e.g. `{(keyword "a :b") :c}`). Just go with the strings.